# What's the use of Lucid Memory Artifacts in Tyranny of King Washington?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I've found a (my first) memory artifact in Assassin's Creed 3 Tyranny of King George (episode 1). I've pressed the "interact" button and a picture appeared; nothing else. The symbol did not disappear from the map. Is that supposed to happen? Can I collect all 3 of them in this episode (The Infamy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting all three is required to achieve 100% synchronization in the Frontier. There are three in the first episode, and they only appear on your map once you get close to them. As well, once you collect all three, a new red assassin icon appears on your map clear off to the Southeast of the Frontier.

I can only imagine that all this will lead up to something with other lucid memories in the future episodes of The Tyranny of King Washington. So I guess you'll just have to wait and see what the big surprise is.

Comment: I've found all three of them. The red icon just shows you a short video of Corner and Washington.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: Like I said,I assume there will be more in the other episodes that will pull it all together. :)

Comment: Spoiler alert!

>! Resumed playing it after a while. Got them all now and nothing extra happens.